# How do I programmatically set gzip in Jetty?

Tags: clojure, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm writing a web app using Noir and clojure, which uses Jetty. Jetty has two ways of using gzip, one for static, and one for dynamic, they are described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113129/104021. I want to turn on both static and dynamic gzipping, but our project doesn't use web.xml files, and doesn't want to start.

How do I *programmatically* set jetty to use gzip (ie without having a web.xml)?

Answer (score 4):

In a Compojure app I'm working on, I have a Ring/Jetty adapter based on [ring-jetty-adapter](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/tree/master/ring-jetty-adapter) which programmatically configures Jetty to use a [GzipHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/GzipHandler.html) to gzip content dynamically.

```
(defn- configurator [server ring-handler]
  (.setHandler server
               (doto (new HandlerCollection)
                     (.addHandler (doto (new GzipHandler)
                       (.setHandler (proxy-handler ring-handler))
                       (.setMimeTypes "text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,text/javascript,image/svg+xml")))
                     (.addHandler (doto (new RequestLogHandler) (.setRequestLog (NCSARequestLog.)))))))
```

This function takes a [Server](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) instance and my Ring handler and sets it up with some handlers. Note that the `GzipHandler` is a `HandlerWrapper`, so it takes my (proxied) Ring handler and delegates to it. I also add a logging handler which will be executed after the (gzip-wrapped) Ring handler.

Check out the [complete working version](https://github.com/lhanson/cognition-caps/blob/master/src/cognition_caps/ring_jetty_adapter.clj).

Answer (score 1):

See the startServer method in here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-servlets/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/GzipWithPipeliningTest.java

jetty uses itself extensively for testing so most embedded scenarios people need already exist in the unit tests somewhere, course finding them can be a bit of an issue :)